# Can't update latest version of PHP using MacPorts

Tags: php, terminal, macports

I have tried using MacPorts to update to the latest version of PHP. After typing
`sudo port install php`
and installing all the necessary packages, when I type `php --version` in the terminal, I still get:

```
PHP 7.3.29 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2021 23:10:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.29, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Why does my computer still have an outdated version of PHP instead of PHP 8?

Answer (score 2):

The `php` port in MacPorts is a shim, it only installs the `/opt/local/share/doc/php/README` file and depends on (currently) `php82`. Click one of the *Files* links on https://ports.macports.org/port/php/details/ to see that.

What gets run when you type `php --version` in your shell depends on the symlink `/opt/local/bin/php`, but that symlink is managed by the port select mechanism explained in the [port-select(1) manpage](https://man.macports.org/port-select.1.html):

> port select provides a mechanism to choose from different
> implementations of a common tool or port. Selecting one of the options
> makes it the primary version or implementation, e.g. the one to be run
> by default when you do not explicitly select a version or
> implementation on the command line.
>
> Note that port select is only for your convenience as user. It does
> not, for example, affect which compiler MacPorts uses when it compiles
> software, or against which copy of MySQL a port builds. If there is a
> user-visible choice, it is usually offered as a variant on the port.
> If the port select mechanism affects how a port builds, that should be
> considered a bug.
>
> One example is the set of MySQL and forks of MySQL, where there are
> mysql51, mysql55, mysql56, mariadb, mariadb-10.0, mariadb-11.0,
> percona, possibly among others. port select lets you choose which of
> these becomes the version run, when you simply run mysql or other
> commands from the MySQL suite.

In your case, you have probably previously used `sudo port select --set php php73`. To make PHP 8.2 your default, run `sudo port select --set php php82`. Run `port select --summary` to see the currently selected option.