# Make MacPorts PHP 7.3 run on OSX Mojave

Tags: php, macos, macports

I am struggling with linking the newly installed PHP version on macOS Mojave (10.14.6)

I've installed PHP 7.3 via MacPorts (I need that exact version right now, I might update it later). Installation went alright, no errors.

When I run `php -v` it gives me

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2020 22:52:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

which, I suppose, is the version shipped with the OS.

My **.bash_profile** looks like this

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/bin   
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:"$PATH"  
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:"$PATH"
export PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

When I run `php73 -v` it logs

```
PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Feb 16 2023 20:14:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.33, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

MacPorts has installed the PHP 7.3 into `/opt/local/bin`.

So obviously, the php version in use by the OS doesn't know about PHP 7.3

Oh, and using homebrew is not really an option. I've just lost hours trying it to install php 8.2 and it failed with one lib or another, constantly claiming that my XCode command line tools are outdated (duh! – and I am not upgrading those as it would require updating the OS to the latest version which would in turn strain my MBP even further).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I need that exact version right now, I might update it later"* - Definitely recommended; PHP 7.X is end-of-life now  https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I know. It's just one step at a time. I need to make this 7.3 work rn, so I can later install and use 8.2. Upgrading the whole hardware just to be able to use PHP8.X – hello Apple & Homebrew – is not an option :)

Comment: Excellent; I figured as much, but I've seen a lot of people trying to install PHP 7.x as their targeted development version, which obviously is not a great idea right now. Apologies, I don't have experience with MacPorts, but hopefully someone will be able to help you 

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo port select --set php php73
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74908814/10763533) for more details.